# Show popups through a menu as well as hover

Tags: jquery

I have developed a tooltip page to show pop ups on mouse over, like a map showing important places. On hover the tooltip shows. How can I activate the same pop up through a menu, because there are more than one pop up used

```html
<div class="tt-wrapper mozy">
  <div class="dyk">
    <span class="tooltip">
      <div class="title">
        <a href="http://www.expo2020dubai.ae/" target="_blank">
          <h3>EXPO 2020 Dubai</h3>
      </div>
      <p>Expo 2020 is a Universal scale Registered Exposition 
time slot sanctioned by the Bureau International des Expositions, Paris on 27 
      November 2013. Dubai in the United Arab Emirates won the right to hold Expo 
2020..</p>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking. The sample HTML you provided shows no popup logic at all...?

Answer (score 0):

You can the title attribute to display the pop up message on html elements

Like :

```
 <p title="A pop up message" >
```

```html
<div class="tt-wrapper mozy">
  <div class="dyk">
    <span class="tooltip">
      <div class="title">
        <a href="http://www.expo2020dubai.ae/" target="_blank">
          <h3>EXPO 2020 Dubai</h3>
      </div>
      <p title="A pop up message" >Expo 2020 is a Universal scale Registered Exposition 
time slot sanctioned by the Bureau International des Expositions, Paris on 27 
      November 2013. Dubai in the United Arab Emirates won the right to hold Expo 
2020..</p>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```